# fechar alertdialog aberto com inflate

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

Tenho um projeto com uma caixa de dialogo aberta com um inflate dando a opção do usuário digitar um texto para assim mudar o valor de uma String.

Estou tendo problemas para fechar essa caixa e voltar ao layout anterior.

```
public class Calendario extends Activity {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Calendario.this);
    String Txt = "Digite sua mensagem";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.calendario );

Txtmessage = (TextView)  findViewById( R.id.EdtMensagemCalendar );
Txtmessage.setText( Txt );

Txtmessage.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View v1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit, null);
            alert.setView(v1);
            alert.create();
            Edt = (EditText)  findViewById( R.id.EdtM );
            alert.show();


        }

    } );
```

o projeto carrega o layout edit dentro da caixa de dialogo corretamente, mas preciso que depois que o usuário digite a mensagem pedida que a caixa de dialogo feche voltando ao layout anterior e fornecendo novo valor ao EditText.

Comment: Obrigado.  Eu usei um inflate porque queria que a caixa de diálogo tivesse um editText, resolvi o problema usando um positivebutton "ok", era o que precisava para fachar o inflate e obter o valor editText.  Não sei por mais não estava conseguindo usar o dismiss, dava erro. Obrigado

Comment: No Edt você precisa colocar -> EditText Edt = (EditText)  v1.findViewById( R.id.EdtM );
pois o edt esta na view inflada v1, caso contrario vai dar nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:
Abrir a caixa de diálogo, e ao clicar no botão OK da caixa do diálogo pegar o texto introduzido, colocá-lo na tal String e fechar a caixa.

Crie um Listener para a caixa de diálogo e sete ela para o botão "OK".

Esse Listener pode fazer isso:

```
        String str = Edt.getText().toString(); //Pegar a String da caixa de diálogo
        alert.dismiss //fechar a caixa de diálogo
```